# Moving a hard drive from one Azure subscription to another

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I have a Windows 2008R2 virtual machine in Azure with an extra 1TB HDD data disk attached.  Can I detach the HDD and move it to another subscription and attach it to a Windows 2016 Server VM that I have in the second subscription?  Should I anticipate any problems or should this go extremely smooth?

If this question does not belong here, please kindly tell me so and suggest a more appropriate forum.

Comment: Are you only looking to move the disk, or are you planning on moving the VM and associated resources?  The process for moving resources between subscriptions is pretty straight forward in most cases, and does not require physically moving the disk if you are moving everything.  Reference:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to find out what type of Data Disk: Managed Disk or Unmanaged Disk.

- If it is Unmanaged Disk, you only need to re-upload the Data Disk to
  new subscription.
- If it is Managed Disk, you go to Resource Group
  where the target Data Disk, then select Move, Move to another
  subscription. Of course, it requires to validate the resource and
  move the disk to other subscription. The amount of time depends on
  the large of the Data Disk.

for more information, see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/move-managed-disks-and-vms-now-available/)

Comment: I asked the wrong question.  The other subscription is under a different account.  I'm guessing you cannot move a drive from one account to the other without using something like Azure Storage Explorer and a snapshot.

Comment: yes, you should Azure Storage Explorer to do it. Nothing choice, I think so. Also from my experience with the large file size, you should always use Azure Storage Explorer to upload. I got many corrupted file with uploading via Azure portal. Hope it helps.